# Rails 3.0.10 before_validation callback not called for associated collection objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an object called a Parent that has_many Child objects:

```
has_many :children
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
```

Child includes a Module that specifies a `:before_validation` callback:

```
def self.included base
  base.class_eval do
    before_validation :my_callback
  end
end

protected
def my_callback
   logger.debug "see me!"
end
```

I've noticed that when creating a Parent and nesting attributes for children, the `:before_validation` callback is not being invoked for each Child. Is this the intended behavior? I've tried doing a `before_save` callback instead and it appears to work fine.

This is on Rails 3.0.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :children
end
```