# invoke method on association before validation check

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
module FullcalendarEngine
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :task
  end
end  

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :fullcalendar_engine_event, class_name: 'FullcalendarEngine::Event'
  validates :name, presence: true
  before_validation :check_if_event
  def check_if_event
    self.name ||= ( fullcalendar_engine_event.present? ? (fullcalendar_engine_event.title || fullcalendar_engine_event.event_category.name) : nil)
    self.name ||= 'Unknown Task'
  end
end
```

In my form:

```
...
<%= f.fields_for :task, f.object.task do |task_builder| %>
...
```

Now I get a validation error that prevents from saving:

```
Task name can't be blank
```

While the check_if_event method is called (I use ruby debugger and put a breakpoint there), the name assignment is not stored. If it was, then this error shouldn't happen.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128313/rails-3-0-10-before-validation-callback-not-called-for-associated-collection-obj) suggests to add a `validates_associated` to Event like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :task
validates_associated :task
```

But all that does is add an additional error in the errors array:

```
Task name can't be blank
Task is invalid
```

I do not know why 'name can't be blank' is showing up in errors array when I assign the name a value in the `before_validation` callback. What am I doing wrong in Rails 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `self.name` **nil**?

In following statement,

```
self.name ||= 'Unknown Task'
```

value will be assigned to `name` if `name` is falsy (nil or false). But if `self.name` is blank string ("") then above statement will not assign any value to `self.name`.

I think , In your case `self.name` is a blank string which is not a falsy value. So it will remain as a blank string. And according to [presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) validation which checks whether the value is empty(means blank and nil values are not permitted) the error will be thrown.

Try changing the same line to

```
self.name = 'Unknown Task' if self.name.blank?
```

Then you will not get any error.

Comment: This is a good point. I will check to see if this is the issue.